# How to implement touch events in uiwebview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, event-handling, touch

I have tried various solutions provided on this site and others to implement touch events on uiwebview. But still I am not able to do this. Actually, i have created a article reader application. Here, I have added a uiwebview on the normal uiview. Now, I want to trace some user touch events on that particular webview.
When I do this on normal view, it works perfectly. But if I try it on webview. it stops working.
The solutions I tried before are

1. implementing touch methods like
   touchbegan
   touchended
   touchmoved
   touch cancelled

2 implementing uigesturerecognizer
3 implementing window touch events like send event

Now If anyone can help me or tell me where I am doing wrong or a new solution(other than this), then I will be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a transparent UIVIew on top of your UIWebView to capture touches. You can then act on them or optionally pass them down to the UIWebView using the touchesBegan deletage method.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.myUIWebView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Check this previous post for details: [iOS - forward all touches through a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834301/ios-forward-all-touches-through-a-view)

Comment: But My uiwebview contains scrolling. Dnt you think that its scrolling will be blocked if I do this.

Comment: I tried your solution bt the problem is the runtime warning occured ie Unable to restore previously selected frame.

Answer (score 0):

I subclassed `UIWebView` and just "leeched" onto its gesture recognizers in subviews 2 levels deep (you could go recursively but thats enough for iOS6-7).
Then you can do whatever you want with the touch location and gesture recognizer's state.

```
for (UIView* view in self.subviews) {
    for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in view.gestureRecognizers) {
        [recognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEvent:)];
    }
    for (UIView* sview in view.subviews) {
        for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in sview.gestureRecognizers) {
            [recognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEvent:)];
        }
    }
}
```