# iPhone - Using jquery-mobile in a UIWebView

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I have never used jquery before, and I am trying to use it on a UIWebView, I though it would be easy but clearly I must be missing something obvious, I kinda followed this SO [JQuery Mobile not working inside UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393490/jquery-mobile-not-working-inside-uiwebview)

I am loading a dynamic html string into my UIWebView and I append at the beginning some styling loaded from a local html file (this works fine), it is something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
//Some style...
                </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/> //Is this what i have to do to load it??
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script> //Is this what I have to do load it???

//Closing tags...
```

I also went to jquerymobile.com downloads and got this 2 files:

```
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js
```

Which I removed from compile sources and added to copy bundle resources, as suggested in the post above.

Then In body I simply added this sample code from http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-collapsible.html

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
   <h3>I'm a header</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
</div>
```

It is my understanding that after doing this, I should be able to tap the div and it would expand and collapse. Right know it just shows all the text in there tapping does nothing.

Any help on what I am missing or a step by step guide would be awesome.

Thank you

Comment: This may sound stupid but did you include jQuery? Also you can also try using jQuery Mobile CDN files directly just to be sure.

Comment: @Gajotres well probably not, what exactly do I have to do include jQuery?

Comment: Just before jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js, jQM cant work without jQuery. Pick version 1.9+

Comment: I will try that, that might be it, thank you!

Comment: I would recommend reading the "Getting Started" section on the jQuery Mobile website (and in general reading at least some documentation before messing with a new framework): http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-mobile/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile needs jQuery to work properly.

Also take care, jQuery Mobile is locked to certain jQuery versions so if you are using **`jQuery Mobile 1.3.1.`** then you would need to use at least **`jQuery 1.8.3`** but I recommend you using version **`1.9`**.

Comment: Thank you, I am sure that is part of the issue, I added version 1.9.1 and added this line:      
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
But it is still not working, I also added the file to the copy bundle resources. Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: It seems like it is definitely doing something now, I forgot to load the files using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, it seems like it cannot find the images assets now, there is supposed to be a + and - image to expand and collapse, I added the zip folder I got from downloads to the project but it still can't find them

Comment: I tried pointing to the cdn i do get the graphics and everything that way, but is there any way to reference this locally?