# Creating a view with accessible to underneath view

Tags: ios, swift

**Problem :**

On the first view i have the view which is displaying the map. i have a button when activated adds an another view on top to show a red border where user can see the actual area. But thats raise an issue which user cannot access or touch the underneath map.

**What i tried**

```
//Create Border
@IBDesignable
class Frame: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        //layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.borderWidth = 10
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    }
}
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: Relevant: [Forward touch events from one view to the view lying underneath it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834301/ios-forward-all-touches-through-a-view)