# Touch event on Visible Portion of Views ios swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, events, touch

I am working of **Photo Collage** which is in `Swift4` , I had created collage using `UIBezierPath` as Below

[image]

I have 5 scroll views in `Storyboard` and the sequence of `Scrollviews` as Below

[image]

Using Following code I am creating **Shapes** :

```
    var path1 = UIBezierPath()
    path1.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: superView.frame.width / 2, y: 0))
    path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: superView.frame.width / 2))
    path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

    var borderPathRef1 = path1.cgPath

    var borderShapeLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
    borderShapeLayer1.path = borderPathRef1

    scroll1.layer.mask = borderShapeLayer1
    scroll1.layer.masksToBounds = true


    var path2 = UIBezierPath()
    path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: superView.frame.width / 2, y: 0))
    path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: superView.frame.width / 2, y: superView.frame.width / 2))
    path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

    var borderPathRef2 = path2.cgPath

    var borderShapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
    borderShapeLayer2.path = borderPathRef2

    scroll2.layer.mask = borderShapeLayer2
    scroll2.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Now the issue is I am not able to get touch event of `Scrollviews` as `Scroll5` is on top. I want to get Touch on Overlapped views like `Scroll1`, `Scroll2` and so on. In Short I need **touch event for particular view on the portion of area where the view is visible.**

**See The Image Below Where I want Touch for Views.**

[image]

How can I get touch on `Overlapped Views`?

Please Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - forward all touches through a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834301/ios-forward-all-touches-through-a-view)

Comment: @ Khushbu Desai. Can you check out the relevant code to Github? The solution can be achieved using somewhere in the lines of https://github.com/Ibrahimhass/SOAnswerIndiaStates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be sure that you set the superView of scrollview to **isUserInterfaceEnabled=true** first.

To get overlapped views touch event:

here is my code:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
let view1: UIView
let view2: UIView
let view3: UIView
let view4: UIView
let view5: UIView

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    view2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    view3.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view3.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view4 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    view4.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    view4.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view5 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    view5.tag = 121
    view5.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addSubview(view1)
    self.addSubview(view2)
    self.addSubview(view3)
    self.addSubview(view4)
    self.addSubview(view5)
    view1.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchAction)))
}

@objc func touchAction () {
    print("----------- touch view 1")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if (view1.point(inside: self.convert(point, to: view1), with: event)) {
        return view1
    }
    return self
}
```

}

The function **hitTest** decides that which view you are touching, so you just need to return the overlapped view.

Comment: How can i get Views using tags? because Scroll5 is on top so every time its returning tag of Scroll 5

Comment: @KhushbuDesai you mean the scroll5 covers all the other 4 scrolls？and you want to get touchEvent from covered scrolls(1,2,3,4)

Comment: @KhushbuDesai As far as I can see from the image you give that the other 4 scrolls are not totally covered by scroll 5, So why can't you get touch events?

Comment: I had created Shapes using UIBezierPath and Constraints for scroll 5 is 0 from all the sides.

Comment: @KhushbuDesai I edit my answer, show you my code. you can have a try.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you.! :)