# how to pass touches to subview with gesture recognizer in parent view swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, subview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have the following case. `parentView` has it's own `gestureRecognizerA`and has a subview `subView` which has it's own `UITapGestureRecognizer`. 
Is there any way to tell `parentView` that it should pass the touch events recognized in `gestureRecognizerA` to `subView` if these touch events are in `subView`'s bounds?

`gestureRecognizerA` is very specific. It is a custom gesture recognizer for recognizing a circlular motion. This recognition should happen on all areas of `parentView`. However, when that same gesture recognizer recognizes a tap, it should pass that tap to `subView`.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - forward all touches through a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834301/ios-forward-all-touches-through-a-view)

Comment: this is not a duplicate, my case is different. I have a parentView and a subView, not some views behind other views...

Comment: If the touches are in subView bound then parentView cant even recognize the touch !. could you just be more specific

Comment: updated the question for more clarity

Comment: you are saying "if these touch events are in subView's bounds". I have a question if touches are in subView's bounds how parentView is going to even reocgnize it ?

Comment: you're right. is there a way that `gestureRecognizerA` also gets the touch events?

Comment: ofcourse it cannot :)

Comment: You can only achieve what you're trying to do by using a single gestureRecognizer

Answer (score 2):

You can easily identify the points of tap.
As for example you have a tap gesture in parent class as:

```
let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)

@objc func tapped(gr:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let loc:CGPoint = gr.location(in: gr.view)  
    //insert your touch based code here
}
```

Inside the tapped method you can identify the location where tap happened, so after checking bounds of the subview with location of tap you can verify is the tap happened inside the bounds of subview or not.

Comment: well, this is indeed a way of doing it, but I want to pass the touch events to the subView. Not calculate it's bounds.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just want both of those gesture recognizers to work simultaneously. Just implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` for your `parentView` and make it `tapGestureRecognizer`'s and `gestureRecognizerA`'s delegate. Then implement an optional method there:

```
// MARK: - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    return true
}
```

That might be able to detect a tap in `subView` even while doing a circular motion within `parentView`.

**UPDATE:** When using gesture recognizers, "forwarding touches" would be to simply calling a method of another recognizer. Just put a recognizer which is doing the forwarding as its parameter.

For instance, `tapGestureRecognizer` fires `viewWasTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` when a tap is detected. Now, when your `gestureRecognizerA` wants to forward its events to `tapGestureRecognizer`, it simply does so by calling:

```
subView.viewWasTapped(self.gestureRecognizerA)
```

With an obvious change to the method itself:

```
func viewWasTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // ...
}
```

This works for `UITapGestureRecognizer`. The sender can be any other `UIGestureRecognizer` and you'd still have almost all the information to resolve a tap gesture there.

Comment: not exactly. I want to have full control over when I want to delegate touch events to the other view.

Comment: Well, you could call a method which is now linked with tapGestureRecognizer. Just make its parameter be of "UIGestureRecognizer" class and pass gestureRecognizerA there. For all intends and purposes, you'd be "forwarding touches" in the world of gesture recognizers.