# Hidden UIButton still receives touch events. The tap recognizer below does not

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an `UIView` which has an `UITapGestureRecognizer` attached to it. I also have an `UIButton` which is a sibling to the mentioned view (i.e. they are placed in the same superview). The button is placed above the view.

The button is sometimes hidden. In this situation I want the taps to go through to the tap gesture recognizer in the view below. However, even though the `hidden` property of the button is set to true it still receives the Touch Up Inside event. It is my understanding that this should not happen since the documentation for the `hidden` property of `UIView` (where the `UIButton` gets the property from) states *A hidden view disappears from its window and does not receive input events.*

I have tried setting both `enabled` and `userInteractionEnabled` properties of the button to false. In both cases the button no longer receives the Touch Up Inside event, but the tap recognizer below it doesn't receive the tap event either.

Is there a way to achieve what I need in my current view hierarchy?

Comment: Please add code.

Comment: Virtually everything I described is set up in Interface Builder, except `button.hidden = YES;` and `button.enabled = NO;` / `button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`.

Comment: @Nick As I explained in my comment above, there really isn't much code related to this issue. Everything is more or les done in Interface Builder. But if you need anything specific let me know.

Comment: You could override the point function, as it's shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834301/ios-forward-all-touches-through-a-view

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding button disable button .
button.isEnabled = false .
So it will not receive events .

Comment: As stated in the question I have already tried doing that, with different, but still unsatisfying results.

Comment: Have you tried removing button from super view and adding to super view when you want it ?

view.bringSubview(toFront: theButton)

removeFromSuperview