# Make sibling view ignore any touch input, the other sibling view should receive it

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, uievent

I develop a Calendar library similar to the default iOS Calendar app, Day View (agenda).

The calendar displays events which are subclasses of the `UIView`. The events can be tapped, long-pressed or could handle other gesture-based user interaction.

Sometimes a `CurrentTimeIndicator` which is also a composed `UIView` subclass could overlap the `Event`.

Both, the `Event` and the `CurrentTimeIndicator` share a common superview, `TimelineView`.

**Together, they look like this:**

[image: timeline view]

When there is no `CurrentTimeIndicator` on top of the `Event`, everything works fine and I could trigger user interaction events by tapping the view. However, when the `CurrentTimeIndicator` overlaps the `Event`, the touch event's received by the indicator are ignored and not passed to the underlying `Event` view.

The goal is to exclude `CurrentTimeIndicator` from the responder chain completely, but let the `Event` handle any touch events, even if obscured by the `CurrentTimeIndicator`.

**View hierarchy:**
[image: view hierarchy]

Both, the indicator and the event are sibling views. When tapping on the event in the highlighted touch are, the touches are not delivered.

So far, I've tried experimenting with `userInteractionEnabled = true / false`, overriding [hitTest:withEvent:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest?language=objc) method.

What are the other approaches to fix the issue?

Code references:

[Event View - creating gesture recognizers](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/blob/master/Source/Timeline/EventView.swift#L46)
[Timeline - layout current time indicator](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/blob/master/Source/Timeline/TimelineView.swift#L278)
[Current Time Indicator - code](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/blob/master/Source/Timeline/CurrentTimeIndicator.swift)

Conceptually, I'm looking to something similar to the [zPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition) property of the `CALayer`, but for the touch input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `pointInside` method inside your CurrentTimeIndicator view:

```
  override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
      print("Passing all touches to the next view (if any), in the view stack.")
      return false
  }
```

as answered here: [iOS - forward all touches through a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834301/ios-forward-all-touches-through-a-view)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Caroline! Surprisingly, I've tried setting `isUserInteractionEnabled=false` in the `CurrentTimelineIndicator` and everything worked like magic.

Before that I've moved detection logic to the `Timeline` completely and checked by invoking `hitTest` whether there is an `EventView` somewhere above it (similar to the approach of using `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the `UICollectionView`).

Proceeding with `isUserInteractionEnabled=false` approach for now, but thank you nevertheless!

Comment: Glad you sorted it out :)