# How to forward all touches of a specific TouchType though a view?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, event-handling, uikit

I'm trying to restrict the handling of touch events for a UIView subclass to certain touch types, i.e. the pencil.

Of course I have read the classic question regarding a similar topic:

[iOS - forward all touches through a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834301/ios-forward-all-touches-through-a-view)

In the discussion I found, that the touches of the event are added to the event at a later stage, which can easily be verified:

```
public override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

    let touches = event?.allTouches // This is always nil, touches are added later :-/

    return super.point(inside: point, with: event)
}
```

So it seems that hit testing can not be manipulated to solve my task… any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what's the issue with `point(inside` ? if self is of a specific type return `super.point(inside: point, with: event)` else return false

Comment: @SandeepBhandari – the issue is that here there is no way to determine the touch type causing the event here: event.allTouches is always nil (and that is by design), so how to find out the source device of the event?