# How can I create a UIView that performs an action on tap but also passes the tap event to the views behind it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I basically want to have an invisible UIView that catches taps on it (and performs some action) but also passes through this tap event to the views behind it. I want to make it some generic class that inherits from UIView.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12355957/1801544 You can make a `PassthroughView` with just that and do what you need.

Comment: @Larme please pay attention that this 'PassthroughView' isn't what I asked. it's a view that checks all its subviews and if the UIEvent is in one of them it says that the event is in it too. I want the opposite.

Comment: What I meant is that you can use that logic, created view and override `pointInside:withEvent:` apply your own logic inside that method to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can propagate touch events through the responder chain:

```
class PassTouchView: UIView {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // do what you want here
        print("View was touched!")
        // propagate up the responder chain (most likely the superview)
        self.next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

Trying to do this with Gesture Recognizers is a bit different. If you want to do that, you probably want to use protocol/delegate pattern.

---

**Edit**

Quick example of protocol/delegate pattern when the "covering view" is using a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

The protocol:

```
protocol PassTapDelegate {
    func passMeTheTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

A custom "pass the tap" view:

```
class PassTapView: UIView {
    
    var ptDelegate: PassTapDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.gotTap(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
    
    @objc func gotTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        print("Got Tap in PassTap view")
        ptDelegate?.passMeTheTap(recognizer)
    }
}
```

A sample view controller showing how to use it:

```
class PassTappingViewController: UIViewController, PassTapDelegate {
    
    var btnsArray: [UIButton] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .systemBlue, .systemGreen, .systemOrange, .systemTeal,
        ]
        let centers: [CGPoint] = [
            CGPoint(x: -75.0, y: -75.0),
            CGPoint(x:  75.0, y: -75.0),
            CGPoint(x: -75.0, y:  75.0),
            CGPoint(x:  75.0, y:  75.0),
        ]
        
        var x: CGFloat = 0
        var y: CGFloat = 0
        var i: Int = 1
        
        for (pt, c) in zip(centers, colors) {
            let b = UIButton()
            b.backgroundColor = c
            b.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: [])
            b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            btnsArray.append(b)
            view.addSubview(b)

            // all buttons are 120 x 120
            b.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0).isActive = true
            b.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b.widthAnchor).isActive = true

            x = pt.x
            y = pt.y
            
            // uncomment these two lines to see the tap passing through
            //  to multiple overlapping buttons
            //x = -75.0
            //y = -75.0 + CGFloat(i) * 40.0

            b.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: x).isActive = true
            b.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: y).isActive = true
            
            i += 1
        }
        
        // add a red PassTapView
        let passTapView: PassTapView = PassTapView()
        
        passTapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        passTapView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        view.addSubview(passTapView)
        
        // center it so it's covering portions of the buttons
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            passTapView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
            passTapView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passTapView.widthAnchor),
            passTapView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            passTapView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        // add action for each button
        btnsArray.forEach { b in
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        
        // set self as the custom delegate for passTapView
        passTapView.ptDelegate = self
        
    }
    
    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        // unwrap the sender as a button and get its title
        guard let b = sender as? UIButton,
              let t = b.currentTitle
        else {
            return
        }
        print("Button \(t) was tapped!")
    }
    
    func passMeTheTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // loop through buttons array to see if tap from
        //  passTapView is inside any of them
        btnsArray.forEach { b in
            if b.bounds.contains(recognizer.location(in: b)) {
                self.btnTapped(b)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

The code will create 4 buttons in a grid, with a `PassTapView` overlaid on top so it covers part of each button:

[image]

Tapping the Red view where it covers part of a button will "pass the tap" gesture to the delegate, which will trigger the `.touchUpInside` action if the tap location is contained in a button.

If we un-comment two lines in the controller (see the comments), it will lay out the buttons in a stack so they overlap each other:

[image]

Now, tapping the left side of the red view will trigger the `.touchUpInside` action for multiple buttons because the tap gesture location will fall inside more than one of them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the Gesture Recognizers approach?

Comment: I want the view with Gesture Recognizers to be ahead of the second view which has a button on it.

Comment: @TamirNahum - it's difficult to offer specific help for an abstract question. But, see the **Edit** in my answer... maybe that will get you on track.