# ShareKit method swizzling in Lion / Xcode 4.3.1?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, sharekit, swizzling

I recently upgraded to Lion and Xcode 4.3.1 with the iOS 5 SDK, and the sharing library [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/) is broken - it used method swizzling for its email handler. Apparently Apple has [banned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720947/method-swizzling-in-ios-5) or at least attempted to phase out method swizzling.

ShareKit imports a file `</usr/include/objc/objc-class.h>`, which no longer exists, and defines its own method swizzling method `SHKSwizzle`. It uses this to alter `MFMailComposeViewController`'s `viewDidDisappear:` method as follows:

```
SHKSwizzle([MFMailComposeViewController class], @selector(viewDidDisappear:), @selector(SHKviewDidDisappear:));
```

What do you think is the best and easiest way to work around this?

Comment: Instead of including `/usr/include/objc/objc-class.h`, include `objc/objc-class.h`, and you are golden.

Answer (score 1):

I have never experienced method swizzling related errors on even on newest XCode and iOS SDK. I use [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit). Though method swizzling is a thing to be avoided in my opinion.

The method swizzled is viewDidDisappear if I remember well. Look what it does. On iOS 5 you can achieve the same using completion block in `- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`.

Just change the way you dismiss the viewController in `- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error` might be enough.

This is just an idea, how you might get rid of method swizzle.

Answer (score 0):

The swizzling is only being used for email sharing.  Use MFMailComposeViewController yourself, and strip the swizzling code out of ShareKit (it's in SHK.m).

Comment: I realize this. I don't want to have to manually rewrap MFMailComposeViewController - I'd prefer to find a way around this so that I can keep the whole sharing system streamlined.