# class_addmethod and Public API

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I am developing a Game Project and wish to use the Object Composition pattern to give me a great deal of flexibility. I currently override message forwarding methods in order that the Composite can invoke the methods of its Components.

The only downside to this is that -forwardingTargetForSelector: only works when there is to be only one target. If I have a Composite with two Components that have the same selector, then I will have to resort to using the (much slower) -forwardInvocation method and perform the NSInvocation on both the targets.

From reading a few books on advanced Objective-C and Runtime reference, it seems that I may be able to forward messages by dynamically creating an implementation that will invoke the IMP in the child Component Classes. I would use the Runtime method class_addmethod to do this.

My question is, does anyone know if Apple considers this to be private API and thus against App Store Rules? Has anyone used class_addmethod in Apps that have passed review?

It is common knowledge that [method swizzling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720947/method-swizzling-in-ios-5) is not allowed in the store, but this is not exactly the same thing. One typical example was swizzling the -drawRect: on UINavigationBar, before the Appearance API was available. This would be adding methods to my own object rather than messing with Apple's own API.

Thanks for Reading!

Lawrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read as long as you're not swizzling Apple provided classes to alter functionality, you should be fine. The Objective-C runtime isn't a private API, so if this is all happening on your own code then you should be fine to do this.