# Receive notification on adding subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

Hello, 
For example, I have a view, on that view there is a scrollview.
Is it possible to know, when any subview has been added on that scrollview without subclassing the UIScrollView and overriding the method `didAddSubview:`? 
Basically, is it possible to receive notifications when the number of subviews has been changed?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to subclass the scroll view?

Comment: @omz just curious. Wanted to find something new.

Comment: Wonder if you could swizzle UIView's implementation of `didAddSubview:` to emit some sort of notification; but this would rely on all UIView subclasses calling the superclass implementation in their own, which is unlikely :(

Comment: Method swizzling could work, but it seems that Apple [doesn't want that in the App Store](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7722169/573626). I think the fact that there is a `didAddSubview:` method that is meant to be overridden in subclasses, indicates that there is no other (good) way to achieve the same thing. If there was a notification mechanism or if it was KVO-compliant, there would be no need for that method...

Comment: I did not know Apple was doing away with swizzling. Just dreadful :) But you're right it probably would have caused more issues than it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Category as well to redefine `didAddSubview:`