# Can you swizzle application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, swizzling

I'm currently working on a product that needs to swizzle the AppDelegate's application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: (I don't want to call my new method in the appDelegate itself).

The thing is: the swizzling simply doesn't work. I've already swizzled methods several times before with success, and this time, the replacing implementation is simply not called. I was wondering if that was because of some specificity of the appDelegate's methods, since these are called by the system, and not the application.

Comment: I don't think Apple likes you swizzling their APIs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720947/method-swizzling-in-ios-5

Comment: By definition, you own the implementation of the app delegate in your own app thus swizzling is unnecessary.  Now, if you are talking about swizzling **other application's** implementation then, no, you can't do that.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to swizzle a method in a class that you define. If you don't want the code in the app delegate, put it in some other method you call from there, or post a notification that some other object receives.

Comment: @Alex, The link you shared is not applicable for this question as the question clearly states that its trying to exchange application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: which is not implemented by Apple, its a documented callback not an implementation (unlike the dealloc as your link mentions.)

Answer (score 4):

I am going to assume most of the things which are missing in your question, Its a great idea to always post the questions with code samples whenever possible.

1. You need to make sure that you are swizzling your methods on the specific implementation of UIApplicationDelegate and NOT the UIApplicationDelegate itself. For Eg

   ```
   @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
   @end
   ```

   In this case you need to swizzle the AppDelegate Class.
2. Also, if you are trying to write a static library/framework you may not know the name of this class at all. In such cases simplest/safest way is to ask for App's AppDelegate name and use that to retrieve a specific class instance via NSClassFromString() or you can just brute force to find the class you need (because you usually have a Single AppDelegate class).

   ```
       unsigned int numberOfClasses = 0;
       Class *classes = objc_copyClassList(&numberOfClasses);
       Class appDelegateClass = nil;
       for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfClasses; ++i) {
           if (class_conformsToProtocol(classes[i], @protocol(UIApplicationDelegate))) {
               appDelegateClass = classes[i];
           }
   }
   ```

**EDIT**

There are a few shortcomings of the above approach,

1. It iterates over all the classes accessible by your application code, looping through all of these classes is not a performant solution.
2. Many famous SDKs will swizzle or dynamically extend your `AppDelegate`, because a lot of interesting things can be intercepted at this single place. This also means that your application may have more than one implementation of `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol and the code above may just pick any implementation of it, causing some serious issues.

As, Chris suggested in comments below, its much safer and performant to just use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate class]`. which should give you the exact AppDelegate implementation known to iOS application at the moment of calling this line of code.

Comment: Why not just use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate class]`?

Comment: @ChrisH , Its much safer and performant to use the way you have shared, I  should update my answer accordingly.