# iOS: How to catch a tap event on a marker on a map that has a CALayer on top of it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `mapView` (RouteMe mapView) on which there are annotations (markers).
On the mapView there is a `touchesEnded` function on which I usually catch all events.
Some markers have an added layer on top of them. 
That layer has some animation images and as much as I know this is the only way I can show these animation images on top of the markers.

The problem is that I don't know how I can intercept a touch on a marker that has that layer on top of it. When I test the hit on the `touchesEnded` I recognize a `CALayer` class rather than a `RMMArker` class (obv0iously, because the layer is on top of the marker, therefore is first to intercept the event).
How can I reach the Marker once the top CALayer is tapped?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the CALayer was on top of a CALAyer, all it took was to access it ancestor `blockingLayer.superlayer`.
By checking on the ancestor, I could have all that I needed.
This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hackish workaround: Create an RMMapLayer instead of a CALayer. Remember to set the annotation on the sublayer to get things like callouts to work, e.g. in your RMMapLayer subclass:

```
RMMapLayer *sublayer = [[RMMapLayer alloc] init];
sublayer.annotation = ann;
sublayer.contents = (id)img2.CGImage;
sublayer.contentsScale = img2.scale;
sublayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)/2, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds)/2);
sublayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, img2.size.width, img2.size.height);
[self addSublayer:sublayer];
```

I don't know how many other things this has potential for breaking though, so you can follow this issue for any updates:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/issues/190

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct the touches to passthrough.  Take a look at this question: [How can I click a button behind a transparent UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046813/how-can-i-click-a-button-behind-a-transparent-uiview/4010809#4010809)

Comment: Thanks @portforwardpodcast for the response. But the answer deals with UIViews. I am using a CALayer