# How to set UICollectionView layer not moving/static while scrolling Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, calayer, cagradientlayer

I added a gradient layer to UICollectionView, but the layer is set to the width of the screen. I am trying to keep the layer static while scrolling but can't find a solution. Tried setting to both the frame of the collectionView and to the currentVC, when I scroll the layer is also scrolling. This is my code so far, thank you for your help.

```
let gradinatLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradinatLayer.frame = self.collectionView.frame //self.currentViewController.view.frame

    let cgColors:[CGColorRef] = [UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7).CGColor, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7).CGColor]

    gradinatLayer.colors = cgColors
    gradinatLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)
    gradinatLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
    gradinatLayer.locations = [0.15, 0.50, 0.85]

    self.collectionView.layer.insertSublayer(gradinatLayer, atIndex: 0)

//This doesn't work
self.collectionView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
self.collectionView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for all your comments. This was my solution after digging into UIView. Unfortunately, adding `super views` and `subviews` to `UICollectionView` still keeps the view scrollable. Thanks to [John Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010809/4697535), who showed how to create a transparent UIView with userIntaractions with its child views, this was possible.

I have declared a `@IBOutlet weak var passThroughView: PassThroughView!` on top of `collectionView`.

This is the code that works now:

```
let gradinatLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradinatLayer.frame = self.currentViewController.view.frame

    let cgColors:[CGColorRef] = [UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7).CGColor, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7).CGColor]

    gradinatLayer.colors = cgColors
    gradinatLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)
    gradinatLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
    gradinatLayer.locations = [0.15, 0.50, 0.85]

    passThroughView.layer.insertSublayer(gradinatLayer, atIndex: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your layer to the collectionView's backgroundview instead:

self.collectionView.backgroundView.layer.addSublayer(gradinatLayer)

Comment: Hi @JDA3, thank you for your answer but this will not work as this is a backgroundView, which means it is behind the cells and won't be visible on top of the cells, hence, we need to add a top layer to the collectionView.

Comment: If you want the gradient above the cells, then you will want to add a new view to the collectionView's .superView, make it transparent, and add the gradient to it.