# How to handle custom UIView button action in TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How do I handle a custom UIView button action inside a TableViewCell?

I have custom UIView with XIB which I added to TableView which is implementet in UIViewControler. For each cell I add my custom UIView in tableView function - cellForRowAt. Everything looks fine but I can't handle button action from added custom UIView for that cell. Can someone help me how to do that?

**Edit:**

My custom UIView which has own XIB.

```
protocol TicketButtonDelegate {
    func starButtonAction(_: UIButton)
}

class TicketView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var ticketContentView : UIView!
    var delegate: TicketButtonDelegate!

    @IBOutlet weak var starButton : UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func commonInit() {

        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TicketView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(ticketContentView)

        starButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(starButtonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        ticketContentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 132)
    }

    @objc func starButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate.starButtonAction(sender)
    }
}
```

My UIViewController.

```
class MhdDashboardBottom: UIViewController, TicketButtonDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mhdTicketsTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mhdTicketsTable.delegate = self
        mhdTicketsTable.dataSource = self
        mhdTicketsTable.register(UINib(nibName: "MhdTicketTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MhdTicketCell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "MhdTicketCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MhdTicketTableCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MhdTicketTableCell")
        }

        let ticket = tickets[indexPath.row]
        let ticketCell = TicketView()
        ticketCell.delegate = self
        ticketCell.tag = 700
        var viewExists = false
        for view in cell.contentCellView.subviews {
            if view.tag == ticketCell.tag {
                viewExists = true
                break
            }
        }
        if viewExists == false {
            cell.contentCellView.addSubview(ticketCell)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 132
    }

    func starButtonAction(_: UIButton) {
        print("Works?")
    }
}
```

My MhdTicketTableCell (UITableViewCell)

```
class MhdTicketTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var contentCellView: UIView!
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Can You explain your target more, i.e. screenshot of what you want.

Comment: I edited my code. Maybe my problem is in adding view (which contains my button) to view of cell in cellForRow method for TableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after very long research for answer I come up with solution.

Into my TicketView I had to add this function to pass touch events into subviews.

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    for subview in subviews {
        if !subview.isHidden && subview.isUserInteractionEnabled && subview.point(inside: convert(point, to: subview), with: event) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

After this, I deleted delegate implementation and I just added

```
ticketCell.starButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(starButtonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

into UIViewControlers cellForRow function and then added objc function

```
@objc func starButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Works?")
}
```

All thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046813/how-can-i-click-a-button-behind-a-transparent-uiview) answered question.

Comment: Weird. I also have buttons inside cells and can easily assign actions there without hit testing...

Comment: I have buttons inside custom UIView which has assigned XIB View which is added as subview to TabvleViewCell container. So touch events weren't handled to my custom UIView.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a protocol use a callback closure, it avoids view hierarchy math, tags and protocol declaration:

- **In the view** delete the protocol

  ```
  protocol TicketButtonDelegate {
     func starButtonAction(_: UIButton)
  }
  ```
- Replace `var delegate: TicketButtonDelegate!` with `weak var callback: (() -> Void)?`
- Replace

  ```
  @objc func starButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
      delegate.starButtonAction(sender)
  }
  ```

  with

  ```
  @objc func starButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
      callback?()
  }
  ```
- **In the controller** delete

  ```
  func starButtonAction(_: UIButton) {
      print("Works?")
  }
  ```
- Replace

  ```
  ticketCell.delegate = self
  ```

  with

  ```
  ticketCell.callback = {
     print("Works?", indexPath)
  }
  ```

The index path and even the `ticket` are captured.

Comment: I tried exactly how you wrote but result is same. I edited my code. Look at method in UIViewController cellForRow where Im adding view to cell. Can be somewhere there problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure that assigning the view causes the issue. Why don't you design and hook up everything in Interface Builder?

Comment: Because I want view of cell to be reusable as View in other parts of app.