# Transparent UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitoolbar

I wrote the following code to make my toolbar transparent.

```
[mtoolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

How do I make `UIToolbar` transparent?

Comment: Do you want a truly transparent toolbar, or just a translucent one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw a transparent UIToolbar or UINavigationBar in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969248/how-to-draw-a-transparent-uitoolbar-or-uinavigationbar-in-ios7)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the property `translucent` to `YES` and see if this helps.

Comment: I think we need to set the property yes

Comment: Edited :) Was just a quick guess, I've not worked directly with the toolbar before.

Comment: Its not working for me. The UIToolbar's background color is in black transparent now. But I need it in clear color.

Comment: See the comment that matches David H's answer.

Comment: Note: if a toolbar is added to the scene, it is *not* referenced by self.navigationController.toolbar - this is the default one owned by the navigationController (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8753847/481207).

Answer (score 11):

```
[self.toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
              forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny
                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self.toolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting the property `translucent` to `YES` will not work in iOS 5 and below. Here's how it can be done without subclassing toolbar:

```
const float colorMask[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(img.CGImage, colorMask)];

[self.toolbar setBackgroundImage:maskedImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the below code

```
[myToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[myToolbar setTranslucent:YES];
```

**Taken from**

**@Brandon Bodnár** has answered in the below SO post.

[Couldn't UIToolBar be transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468831/couldnt-uitoolbar-be-transparent)

you could also use the different approach

[Transparent UIToolBar](http://blog.blackwhale.at/2010/07/transparent-uitoolbar/)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (UIView * sv in [toolBar subviews])
{
     [sv removeFromSuperview];
}
```

;) any iOs

Answer (score 1):

The following works in iOS 5 (and iOS 6 beta 4, although a slight top shadow is still visible there).

**Please note:**
Making a UIToolbar or UINavigationBar transparent is rarely a good idea, and modifying Apple's UIKit elements in such a way is bound to break sooner or later.

**TransparentToolbar.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TransparentToolbar : UIToolbar

@end
```

**TransparentToolbar.m**

```
#import "TransparentToolbar.h"

@implementation TransparentToolbar

-(void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    //  This method is called with a view of class "UINavigationBarBackground" or "_UIToolbarBackground", respectively. It would be possible to check for this with NSStringFromClass([view class]) to be completely sure that we're skipping the right view.

    if (index != 0)
    {
        [super insertSubview:view atIndex:index];
    }
    else
    {
        // insert your custom background view, if you want to
    }
}


@end
```

**EDIT:** In iOS 5+, it's also possible to simply set the backgroundImage (which could be transparent). This is certainly the "cleaner" solution, but is less flexible than a custom `UIView`.

```
[someToolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clear"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for iOS 6 and 7:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1, 1), NO, 0.0);
UIImage *blank = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self.toolBar setBackgroundImage:blank forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: There is still a border shown. Is there a fix for it ?