# How to make a UIToolbar show up in Storyboard for visual editing

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4

I'm trying to make a UIToolbar that I manually inserted in the bottom part of a view controller (shown below) appear in the Storyboard visual editor.

[image: toolbar is the right-most icon]

I can still add drag objects inside it using Document Outline by clicking on the triangle in the bottom-left corner and dragging objects there, but I'd like to see it so that I'll know it looks right, like this:

[image: toolbar that can be visually edited]

Comment: There is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707540/visually-modifying-a-uitoolbar-from-xcode-storyboard) that was given an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you drag-and-dropped the `UIToolbar` into the black rectangle beneath a scene in the storyboard, judging from your picture.

Try this: the way to add a `UIToolbar` is to go to the Attributes inspector (CMD+OPTION+4) and set the Bottom Bar to Toolbar:

[image]

You'll then see the `UIToolbar` in your scene and can customize it from there!

Comment: I'm already using that bottom bar for something else. I wanted to add a second bottom bar so that I'll be able to dynamically switch between the items of the two. Thanks for answer, but I already found a solution (and StackOverflow doesn't allow me to post it yet.

Comment: Why two bottom bars? You can always remove / add buttons to the UIToolbar programmatically --- no need for two separate UIToolbars

Comment: I'd like to maintain as little code as possible. Actually, I could also do everything the Storyboard does programmatically, but why would I want to...

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this. I had views not inside the ViewController and wanted to visually see them.
You can get them to show up on the storyboard with this method.
Open the Assistant Editor (middle button of the first set of buttons top right)
Select any of the available link rings in whatever view controller .h that shows up. It doesn't matter if they are linked or not.
Click and drag from the ring to the panel on the left of the storyboard with your list of items in and hover over one of the items that are on your toolbar and it should just pop into view.
Don't let go of mouse button until you move back to where the ring was so you don't accidentally create a link.

Comment: I've found a better solution, but I won't be able to post it for the next 8 hours...

Comment: Another thing I sometimes do is drag it into an existing view, make changes, then drag it out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an Xcode bug (still there at v4.3.1), but I've found a workaround:

1. Add a Segmented Control inside the toolbar you'd like to edit visually (like it was explained in the question above) -- the toolbar will show up somewhere on the Storyboard.
2. Remove that Segmented Control -- the toolbar will stay.