# How to make UIToolbar have a Clear Background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I have a UIToolbar that has a white tint, with a bar button item, followed by some flexible space, followed by another bar button item. I would like to make the toolbar completely clear so that I can see what is under the flexible space (I don't care about seeing what is behind the buttons). Is there a way to do this?
I have tried setting the toolbar to translucent, but that does not make it completely clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent UIToolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250439/transparent-uitoolbar)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7027807/653513

Comment: Hey guys, sorry about the duplicate. I didn't notice the other one. Please close the question and mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
[self.toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
              forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny
                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

 [self.toolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: This approach was the only one working when inserting a transparent UIToolbar as a NavigationItem.TitleView.

Comment: On ios7.1, i'm seeing a 1px border (shadow?) at the top of the toolbar.

Comment: @Chris, I noticed the same thing. Not sure how to fix it. Luckily i'm needing to do this in a popup where the view's border color is black. So i've just moved the toolbar up so the shadow (or whatever it is) gets lost in the border.

Comment: @Andrew - I used setShadowImage:forToolbarPosition: to set the shadow image to [[UIImage alloc] init]

Comment: Note: if a toolbar is added to the scene, it is *not* referenced by self.navigationController.toolbar - this is the default one owned by the navigationController (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8753847/481207).

Comment: Swift Version .:  self.toolbar.isTranslucent = true
        self.toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),
                                   forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.any,
                                   barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)
        
        self.toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.any)

Answer (score 8):

Subclass UIToolbar, and implement the below method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
  [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.6f] set]; // or clearColor etc
  CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
}
```

see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250439/transparent-uitoolbar)

Comment: So this is a duplicate question?

Comment: Close the question and mark it a duplicate of the one you linked to.

Comment: This is indeed the correct way to do it.  It is quite an annoyance though that it cannot be customized without subclassing...

Comment: You can customize it without subclassing - see @NANNAV's point below. More elegant IMHO, mind you -1 doesn't fit into UIBarStyle's enum in `UIInterface.h`. But what could possibly go wrong? :S

Comment: Excellent for my case, however not for every one will suit

Answer (score 5):

set toolbarStyle -1 like this

```
 tools.barStyle = -1; // clear background
```

Comment: Works for me on iOS 11!

Comment: This was the only approach that worked for me with Xcode 13 and iOS 15. But as the other postings mention it leaves a 1 px dark bar at the top to the toolbar

Comment: This works well in light mode but not dark mode, will have to use the recommended (with setShadow too) to completely fix this

Comment: Xcode 15 beta 5 -> Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'UIBarStyle', can't seem to hack my way around it...

Answer (score 2):

Hacky, sorry, but the only way I've found so far that reliably works in both iOS 7 and iOS 6 is to do this:

```
[[toolbar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: always use prefer `firstObject` instead of `objectAtIndex:0`

Comment: Thanks @Tuss.  In my defence, in iOS 6, `firstObject` was a private API. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution in **@ievgen** answer in Swift 5.1

```swift
toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any, barMetrics: .default)
toolbar.backgroundColor = .clear
```

If you want to clear the separator gray line

```swift
toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a global solution take advantage of the `UIAppearance` proxy:

`UIToolbar *toolbarAppearance = [UIToolbar appearance];
    [toolbarAppearance setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without subclassing in iOS 6+ with setting the property `translucent` to `YES.

This will not work in iOS 5 in below. Here's how it can be done without subclassing toolbar:

```
const float colorMask[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(img.CGImage, colorMask)];

[self.toolbar setBackgroundImage:maskedImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3 version of accepted answer:

```
   self.toolbar.isTranslucent = true
    self.toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),
                               forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.any,
                               barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)

    self.toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.any)
```