# MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem functionality, but not in a stupid bar button

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

Historic question. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkusertrackingbutton is now available.

---

When you use the ordinary Map app on ios,

[image]

of course you have the blue pointer button, which cycles you through the "tracking" modes.  (Show your own location, etc)

MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem does this, but it's a stupid bar button.  I don't have a bar and don't want a bar, I have a normal MKMapView.

- Can I make the "blue arrow button" simply appear on my MKMapView (nothing to do with a #$@ bar)?  Much as in the above image
- Or can I just use any old ordinary button, ***but have it do the same functionality?***
- Minor - if "B", in fact is there a way to get at that blue-arrow icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, iOS doesn't expose an isolated version of `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem`. (You might want to file a radar to request this. Feel free to dupe [mine](http://openradar.appspot.com/28740675).)

I suggest embedding `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` in a `UIToolbar` with a [clear background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16035779/235297).

Answer (score 8):

Just call `addMapTrackingButton()` inside `viewDidLoad` method:

```
func addMapTrackingButton(){
    let buttonItem = MKUserTrackingButton(mapView: eventsMapView)
    buttonItem.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:5, y: 25), size: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35))

    eventsMapView.addSubview(buttonItem)
}
```

Comment: Anyway to add this in interface builder?

Answer (score 1):

Use `MKUserTrackingButton` which is UIView!

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkusertrackingbutton