# UIToolbar to have translucent and not black color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitoolbar

What is the most easiest way (if possible without using drawRect, subclassing, category) to have a transparent UIToolbar with not a Black color, a color of my own choice? I know you can set the translucent property of a UIToolbar, but the color is black, I tried setting the background color but it didn't work. I tried setting the background image and it works but it is not transparent then.

Comment: Could we see some code on how you're setting up the toolbar and its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `setTintColor:` method. For example:

```
[self.navigationController.toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: setting the tint color doesn't help.. it's still black

Comment: Since iOS 7 (or 8), tint color is use to change the text and image, instead of the background. So this piece of code does not work any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using IB, it should work:

1. set Tint color of toolbar to your choice of color.
2. set Alpha of toolbar to 0.5 or the according to the transparency you want.

Comment: It works but it's not quite the same as what a translucent toolbar looks like: with this approach the buttons (and their labels) are opaque too, and ideally their labels should be at full opacity for better legibility.

Answer (score 0):

answers with code sample can be found in this question: [Couldn't UIToolBar be transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468831/couldnt-uitoolbar-be-transparent)

seba