# How to make UIToolbar's background transparent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitoolbar

I want to make my UIToolBar have a transparent background (similar to iBooks) but I'm having no luck with setting the `translucent` property.

Here's my code:

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    NSMutableArray *toolBarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil]];
    [toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Source" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil]];
    [toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Aa" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil]];
    [toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Rabbit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil]];
    toolBar.items = toolBarItems;
    toolBar.translucent = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

It still comes out like this:

[image]

Comment: I believe you will need to set a transparent background image in order to do this. Just create a 1x1 pixel transparent png.

Comment: @doug Smithh as uitoolbar is a subclass of uiview you can use it's layer property to make it transparent by changing the value of alpha

Comment: Have a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468831/couldnt-uitoolbar-be-transparent#answer-3253738

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want toolbar as 
 **Transparent :**

```
[toolBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and if you want toolbar as **Translucent** :

```
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
toolBar.translucent = YES;
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Could you explain the method you used for transparent?

Comment: The Transparent method still show a thin bar at the top of the toolbar border, how to get rid of that?

Comment: Nice elegant solution for iOS 7

Comment: It seems that in iOS 7 you have to have all three lines of code in order to get transparency. If I set translucent = NO, there seems to be no way to get transparency in the toolbar at all

Comment: @Malloc: [toolbar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny];

Comment: Thanks, good solution! Trannslucent in storyboard en the first line in code fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to subclass UIToolbar and override the draw method, the buttons will continue to draw themselves as normal:

```
@interface TransparentToolbar : UIToolbar 
{
}

@implementation TransparentToolbar

// drawRect stub, toolbar items will still draw themselves
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    return;
}

@end
```